# On div hover show marker infowindow in google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, joomla2.5

I have a page which is loading a google map with markers depending on the search results. The search results are some divs in tandem. When someone hovers over a div i want the respective marker on the google map to show its infowindow. Is that somehow possible?

I provide the jquery code below. If any code from another page is needed please inform

```
if (typeof SPGeoMapsModReg == 'undefined') {
    var SPGeoMapsModReg = {}
}
function SPGeoMapModInit(a, b) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        SPGeoMapsModReg[a] = new SPGeoMapMod(a).init(b)
    })
}
function SPGeoMapMod(h) {
    this.Options;
    this.Map;
    this.Position;
    this.Markers = [];
    this.cid = h + 'Inner';
    this.Container = jQuery('#' + h);
    this.Canvas = jQuery('#' + this.cid);
    this.InfoWindow;
    this.init = function(a) {
        this.Options = a;
        this.Container.css('width', a.mapWidth).css('height', a.mapHeight).css('background-color', 'black').css('background', 'url(media/sobipro/progress/ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat').fadeTo('slow', 0.2);
        this.getEntries();
        return this
    };
    this.getEntries = function() {
        var b = this;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'option': 'com_sobipro',
                'task': 'geomod.load',
                'sid': this.Options.sid,
                'format': 'raw',
                'section': this.Options.pid,
                'ctask': this.Options.task
            },
            success: function(a) {
                b.InitMap(a)
            }
        })
    };
    this.InitMap = function(a) {
        this.Position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(this.Options.startLatitude), parseFloat(this.Options.startLongitude));
        var b = [];
        for (i = 0; i < this.Options.availableViews.length; i++) {
            b[i] = google.maps.MapTypeId[String(this.Options.availableViews[i]).toUpperCase()]
        }
        var c = {
            zoom: parseFloat(this.Options.zoomLevel),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId[String(this.Options.defaultView).toLocaleUpperCase()]
        };
        for (var i in this.Options.mapOptions) {
            c[i] = this.Options.mapOptions[i]
        }
        if (b.length > 0) {
            c['mapTypeControlOptions'] = {
                mapTypeIds: b
            }
        }
        this.Canvas.css('width', this.Options.mapWidth).css('height', this.Options.mapHeight);
        this.Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.cid), c);
        this.Map.setCenter(this.Position);
        var d = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.entries.length; i++) {
            var e = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(a.entries[i].latitude), parseFloat(a.entries[i].longitude));
            var f = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position': e
            });
            f.sid = a.entries[i].sid;
            google.maps.event.addListener(f, 'mouseover', function() {
                d.OpenInfo(this)
            });
            this.Markers.push(f)
        }

        var g = new MarkerClusterer(this.Map, this.Markers);
        this.Container.fadeTo('slow', 1).css('background', 'none');
        if (a.msg.length) {
            alert(a.msg)
        }
    };
    this.OpenInfo = function(b) {
        var c = this;
        try {
            this.InfoWindow.close()
        } catch (e) {}
        this.InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        this.InfoWindow.setContent('<img src="media/sobipro/progress/ajax-loader.gif"/>');
        this.InfoWindow.open(this.Map, b);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'option': 'com_sobipro',
                'task': 'geomod.info',
                'sid': b.sid,
                'format': 'raw',
                'iid': c.Options.iid
            },
            success: function(a) {
                c.InfoWindow.setContent(a.html)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The website is a beta version and is under construction so it doesnt have lot of entries and it is in greek language. So you can simply type the k letter in the search field in this address [link](http://asfalistes.gr/sobi/search/results) to get some results. The final result i need is something like this [link](http://farmersagent.com/Results.aspx?isa=1&name=alex&csz=CA). Hope this helps

Comment: Your [example](http://asfalistes.gr/sobi/search/results) seems to be working, what is your question?

Comment: What i want is, when i hover my mouse over an entry (on the left column where the entries are listed), automatically the marker of the respective entry to show its infowindow (on the map on the right column). An example of what i need is here [link](http://farmersagent.com/Results.aspx?isa=1&name=alex&csz=CA)

Comment: The website is currently locked, you can enter by using visitor as username and visitor_12345 as password.